# Replace equal with semicolon in Java Script Object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am sending the `Map<String,String>` object from servlet to jsp whose key is `attribute name` and value `jsonvalue`. My Requirement is to collect the value of key in variable that is root here. But when I tried to assign these map object to JavaScript variable i'ts throwing an error because the map object contains the `=` operator in the data. So to remove the error I assigned `=` with `:` manually its working fine.

So please tell me how do I remove the `=` with `:` with JavaScript code? Or is there any way to send the data with semicolon from servlet?

The data is coming in this format:

```
var trees=   {dage={"nodeId":3,"value":"0-7","children":[{"nodeId":2,"value":"4-7","children":[{"nodeId":1,"value":"6-7","children":[{"nodeId":0,"value":"7","children":[]},{"nodeId":4,"value":"6","children":[]}]},{"nodeId":6,"value":"4-5","children":[{"nodeId":5,"value":"5","children":[]},{"nodeId":7,"value":"4","children":[]}]}]},{"nodeId":10,"value":"0-3","children":[{"nodeId":9,"value":"2-3","children":[{"nodeId":8,"value":"3","children":[]},{"nodeId":11,"value":"2","children":[]}]},{"nodeId":13,"value":"0-1","children":[{"nodeId":12,"value":"1","children":[]},{"nodeId":14,"value":"0","children":[]}]}]}]}, 

dpob={"nodeId":6,"value":"4;3;5;6;1;2;0","children":[{"nodeId":5,"value":"0","children":[{"nodeId":4,"value":"0","children":[{"nodeId":3,"value":"0","children":[{"nodeId":2,"value":"0","children":[{"nodeId":1,"value":"0","children":[{"nodeId":0,"value":"0","children":[]}]}]}]}]}]},{"nodeId":12,"value":"4;3;5;6;1;2","children":[{"nodeId":11,"value":"3;5;6;1;2","children":[{"nodeId":10,"value":"5;6;1;2","children":[{"nodeId":9,"value":"2","children":[{"nodeId":8,"value":"2","children":[{"nodeId":7,"value":"2","children":[]}]}]},{"nodeId":15,"value":"5;6;1","children":[{"nodeId":14,"value":"1","children":[{"nodeId":13,"value":"1","children":[]}]},{"nodeId":17,"value":"5;6","children":[{"nodeId":16,"value":"6","children":[]},{"nodeId":18,"value":"5","children":[]}]}]}]},{"nodeId":22,"value":"3","children":[{"nodeId":21,"value":"3","children":[{"nodeId":20,"value":"3","children":[{"nodeId":19,"value":"3","children":[]}]}]}]}]},{"nodeId":27,"value":"4","children":[{"nodeId":26,"value":"4","children":[{"nodeId":25,"value":"4","children":[{"nodeId":24,"value":"4","children":[{"nodeId":23,"value":"4","children":[]}]}]}]}]}]}]}}
```

I am trying to iterate this map working fine if : is there to get the key.

```
for (var key in trees){
    if(key===attribute_name){
        root=trees[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the jsp code through which i am getting the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var treeStructure=<%=request.getAttribute("treeData")%>;
<script>
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? They are not the same thing, but you have both tags on your question. Or are you sending something from a Java program to a JavaScript program?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat sending the map from java so is there any possibility in java to send map with key:value cause its coming like this key=value

Comment: You need to post the Java code where you're printing out the javascript object.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat is both: Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `Map<String, String>` into a JSON string using a JSON parse library. Then, set this data into a variable in your JavaScript code (after parsing it properly).

Here's an example using Jackson library.

Java servlet (or whatever controller you use) code:

```
Map<String, String> yourMap = ...;
//fill your map...
request.setAttribute("theMapAsJSON", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourMap));
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var treeStructure = JSON.parse('${theMapAsJSON}'); //naive approach
<script>
```

Comment: My map contain already a json as a value.I Have tried that using gson.toJson(map); and getting data but now data is coming in the format "dage":"jsonData" etc .Because key is coming from dropdown list based upon that i am checking condition if dropdown value is there in map get the value.

Comment: @henrycharles then use another String formatting that enable the interoperability between your Java structure and your JavaScript consumer. Note that this may not be that easy.